# Butterknife fails with Gradle plugin 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, butterknife

I was using Butterknife in my project and after updating Android Studio and Gradle plugin to version 3.1.2, I can not continue using Butterknife.
Has anyone faced this problem and resolved it?
I have considered eliminating Butterknife and using Android Data Binding, is it a good option?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not continue using Butterknife"? Does it yeild any errors? If so, could you post them here?

Comment: please add log cat  error here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Add this dependency in your app.gradle file .its work fine with **Android studio 3.1.2** .may be you have some other problem with gradle.

> **New Approach**

**In app.gradle**

```
 implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

**In project.gradle**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

If you use these plugin in **app.gradle** then **Remove** these lines.

> **Old Approach**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

**project.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
```

Comment: I removed the old plugin and It worked. I am still trying to solve other issues to get the project compiling, but I think the butterknife problem is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think,there is some other problem please use this dependency.

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```